# How to sort a dictionary by value if the value is a sorted list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a dictionary based on the value (which is a sorted list).
for example, I have these dictionary items:

```
1:[2, 6, 10, 14, 20, 46]
2:[1, 2, 3, 14, 16, 18, 23, 37, 41]
3:[1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 27, 45, 290]
4:[3, 5, 13, 34, 39, 40, 47, 555]
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
2:[1, 2, 3, 14, 16, 18, 23, 37, 41]
3:[1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 27, 45, 290]
1:[2, 6, 10, 14, 20, 46]
4:[3, 5, 13, 34, 39, 40, 47, 555]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
x = {
1:[2, 6, 10, 14, 20, 46],
2:[1, 2, 3, 14, 16, 18, 23, 37, 41],
3:[1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 27, 45, 290],
4:[3, 5, 13, 34, 39, 40, 47, 555]
}

b = sorted(x.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[(2, [1, 2, 3, 14, 16, 18, 23, 37, 41]), (3, [1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 27, 45, 290]), (1, [2, 6, 10, 14, 20, 46]), (4, [3, 5, 13, 34, 39, 40, 47, 555])]
```

Comment: you could even do this without assigning to `a` first `sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: Thanks! that was very helpful.